# Prestashop 1.6 blocktopmenu how to add classes to each li

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I`m changing the current default Prestashop template, and I need custom classes in module blocktopmenu for li.

Does anybody know how to implement this functionality?

Well the blocktopmenu.tpl looks like this:

```
{if $MENU != ''}
<!-- Menu -->
<div id="block_top_menu">
    <ul class="menu_top">
        {$MENU}
    </ul>
</div>
<!--/ Menu -->{/if}
```

In frontend the code looks like this:

```
<div id="block_top_menu">
<ul class="menu_top">
<li>
<a title="Company" href="link-example">Company</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Realizations" href="link-example">Realizations</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Questions" href="link-example">Questions</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Lets work together" href="link-example">Lets work together</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="contact" href="link-example">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There are some other files related in thismodule but they are too long to paste the code here, so I thik it`s a question to smb that knows PrestaShop.

Thanks guys for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The markup for the menu is generated in the file: `/modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.php`

The `makeMenu()` function contains a switch block which shows the functions used to build the markup for each type of link in the menu.

If you want to modify the markup for categories, then you need to modify the `generateCategoriesMenu()` function. For CMS pages added to the menu, it looks like the `getCMSMenuItems()` function is where you need to make changes.

For example, I modified `generateCategoriesMenu()` to add an id to the menu links like this:

```
$html .= '<li id="cat-'. (int)$category['id_category'] .'" >'
```

Comment: yup...editing "generateCategoriesMenu()" function within in the blocktopmenu.php file worked for me: ps 1.6 thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a CSS solution to this:

```
.menu_top li:nth-child(1) { ... }
.menu_top li:nth-child(2) { ... }
.menu_top li:nth-child(3) { ... }
```

We`ll it`s not dynamic but this will do for a short period.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solutions for this problem

```
protected function generateCategoriesMenu($categories, $is_children = 0)
{
    $html = '';

    foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {

    if ($category['level_depth'] > 1) {
            $cat = new Category($category['id_category']);
            $link = Tools::HtmlEntitiesUTF8($cat->getLink());
            $class_li_id = $category['id_category'];

        } else {
            $link = $this->context->link->getPageLink('index');
        }

        /* Whenever a category is not active we shouldnt display it to customer */
        if ((bool)$category['active'] === false) {
            continue;
        }

        $rUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if(stristr($rUrl,$category['id_category']) && !stristr($rUrl,'.html')) {

        }

        if($category['level_depth'] == 3) { 
            $html .= '<li'.(($this->page_name == 'category'
                && (int)Tools::getValue('id_category') == (int)$category['id_category']) ? '' : '').' class="addPoint addPoint_'.$category['position'].'" data-point="'.$category['position'].'">';
         } else {

            $html .= "<li class=\"menu_top$class_li_id\">";

         }   
        $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$category['name'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a>';

        if (isset($category['children']) && !empty($category['children'])) {



            $html .= '<ul>';
                $html .= $this->generateCategoriesMenu($category['children'], 1);
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }

        $html .= '</li>';

    }

    return $html;
}
```

// i add this - **$class_li_id = $category['id_category'];**

and now my top menu has a class with category id

example **`<li class="menu_top13">`**